# Finding maximum Collatz sequence between 1-1000000

Tags: c++, performance, collatz-sequence

I'm trying to find maximum the [Collatz sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Statement_of_the_problem) between 1 and 1000000. I wrote the following code below. I guess it is correct but it is extremely slow. Can you give me a few hints to make it faster?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
bool myfn(int i, int j) { return i<j; }

int collatz(int x);

int main()
{
    vector <int> myvector;
    for(int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        myvector.push_back(collatz(i));
    }

    cout<<*max_element(myvector.begin(),myvector.end(),myfn);


    return 0;

}

int collatz(int x)
{
    int counter = 1;


    while(1)
    {
        if(x == 1)
            break;

        if(x % 2 == 0)
        {
            x = x / 2;
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            x = 3 * x + 1;
            counter++;
        }
    }

    return counter;
}
```

Comment: Just a minor point: `x = x / 2` can be shortened to `x /= 2`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your program is non-portable, since an [`int` is only guaranteed to hold numbers up to 32767](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589684/1157100).  I would change your data type to `unsigned long long`; otherwise, [`collatz(159487)`](http://oeis.org/A222292/internal) will overflow.

---

Your `while` condition is clumsy.

```
while(1)
{
    if(x == 1)
        break;
    …
}
```

should just be

```
while (x != 1)
{
    …
}
```

---

The key insight is that if you already know, for example, the value of `collatz(37)`, then `collatz(74)` is just `1 + collatz(74 / 2)`, and you can reuse the previously computed result.  Therefore, your `collatz()` function should have access to the results vector — either

1. pass it in by reference, or
2. make the vector an instance variable, and the function a method of the class.

It turns out that recursion works quite well for this problem: every chain will terminate in a few hundred steps, so your function call chains will be at most a few hundred frames deep.  Using recursion allows you to cache the result for every number along the chain, which you can't do using iteration.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

int collatz(unsigned long long n, std::vector<int> &results) {
    int c;
    if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else if (n < results.size() && results[n]) {
        return results[n];
    } else if (n % 2 == 0) {
        c = 1 + collatz(n / 2, results);
    } else if (n >= (std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max() - 1) / 3) {
        throw std::overflow_error("Overflow");
    } else {
        c = 1 + collatz(3 * n + 1, results);
    }
    if (n < results.size()) {
        results[n] = c;
    }
    return c;
}

int main() {
    const unsigned long long N = 1000000ULL;
    std::vector<int> results(N);
    int max = 0, max_i;
    for (unsigned long long i = 1; i < N; ++i) {
        results[i] = collatz(i, results);
        // std::cout << "collatz(" << i << ") = " << results[i] << std::endl;
        if (max < results[i]) {
            max = results[i];
            max_i = i;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Max: " << max_i << " with " << max << " steps" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

By packaging your code into a class, you can let `main()` not worry about some of the details:

```
template <typename T>
class Collatz {
  public:
    Collatz(T limit) : limit(limit), results(limit) {}

    int operator[](T n) {
        int c;
        if (n == 1) {
            return 1;
        } else if (n < results.size() && results[n]) {
            return results[n];
        } else if (n % 2 == 0) {
            c = 1 + (*this)[n / 2];
        } else if (n >= (std::numeric_limits<T>::max() - 1) / 3) {
            throw std::overflow_error("Overflow");
        } else {
            c = 1 + (*this)[3 * n + 1];
        }
        if (n < results.size()) {
            results[n] = c;
        }
        return c;
    }

    const T limit;

  private:
    std::vector<int> results;
};    

int main() {
    Collatz<unsigned long long> collatz(1000000ULL);
    int max = 0, max_i;
    for (unsigned long long i = 1; i < collatz.limit; ++i) {
        // std::cout << "collatz(" << i << ") = " << collatz[i] << std::endl;
        if (max < collatz[i]) {
            max = collatz[i];
            max_i = i;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Max: " << max_i << " with " << max << " steps" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **make the vector an instance variable, and the function a method of the class.** Can you make this a little bit more clear? I couldn't understand. Thanks for such a helpful answer by the way.